# CQ5 sidekick elements disabled

Tags: aem

I have an issue where at a specific path the sidekick items are disabled and I can't edit components on those pages.  I'm logged in as admin and from the siteadmin I can't delete or move pages.  If I go a node level lower or switch websites I have all of these permissions.

All if the items in the sidekick are visible but are greyed out.  I can't see page properties when I'm on the siteadmin page either.

After reviewing the javascript console I see this happening:

charset=utf-8&cq_ck=1389020093589">http://testsetver.com:4502/home/users/a/admin.permissions.json?path=%2Fcontent%2Fwebsite&*charset*=utf-8&cq_ck=1389020093589 404 (Not Found) widgets.min.js:19516

Comment: Have you tried the design mode in the sidekick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen similar behaviour when we had content moved via a package and it ended up creating a page without an associated jcr:content node. This doesn't have to be on the page that you are having problems with, it could be a sibling page. I would check the integrity of the pages under that website.

Comment: That is correct.  We had added a new node structure for metadata and it was missing the jcr:content node.  Once I added that to the structure the issue resolved itself.  thanks!

Comment: Facing the same issue, but the page in fact does have a jcr:content node, any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I didn't read the second part regarding that it could be another page missing the jcr:content node.