# CQ5 same template for two pages

Tags: aem

I am using a template "home-template" for two pages.

First page is root page called "CompanyABC"
root page child page is "english"
"english" child page is "home"

"CompanyABC" and "home" pages created using same template "home-template"

"home" page is working as expected.
But "CompanyABC" page is having following errors in browser console and page is not working as expected ( All parsys and included components divs have "display : none" )

Following is the error in browser console

[image]

I really appreciate if anyone could shed some light on this, If I create any new root page, or immediate child page with the **ANY** template the issue is reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A corrupt/missing `jcr:content` node somewhere in your page hierarchy could cause this issue.  See [CQ5 sidekick elements disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913655/cq5-sidekick-elements-disabled).

I recommend using Content Explorer as an admin and looking at each node in your /content directory all the way down to the pages where you see issues to make sure each one has the jcr:content node it should.

Comment: I accept @Shawn answer. As I uninstall, install AEM instance, the issue is gone. It seems issue is something to do with content.